# What number appears most often in an $n \times n$ multiplication table?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is precisely as stated in the title:

> What number appears most often in an $n \times n$ multiplication table?

**Note:** By "an $n \times n$ multiplication table" I mean the multiset

$$M_n := \{a \cdot b: \mathbb{Z}^{+}\ni a, b \leq n \} $$

I realize the answer is often [not unique](http://oeis.org/A064048) - though one could make it so by asking for [the minimal entry](http://oeis.org/A057144) in the case of a tie - but I am wondering whether there is a general approach to this question.

I am *not sure* about how difficult this problem is; for example, a related question about distinct entries turns out to be quite nontrivial: See the discussion of the Erdos Multiplication Table problem, which was formulated in the mid-twentieth century and resolved only recently by Ford (2008), in the MathOverflow post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/108939).

Comment: Interesting question! It is probably not possible to give an explicit recipe. There are estimates for the *number* of times the most popular number appears, since there are estimates for the maximum value of $d(k)$ as $k$ ranges over the natural numbers $\le n$.

Comment: It seems [somewhat rare](http://oeis.org/A064048) for this question to have a unique answer.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A057144 seems to be closer to the numbers asked for.

Comment: Will it not most probably just be numbers from the list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number or what am I missing?

Comment: Not quite. For the solution x, you don't count the number of factors, you count the number of factors f with x/n <= f <= n. I suppose you can go through the numbers <= n with maximum number of factors and find an x with a large number of factors in the right range, then examine all x with at least that many factors, hoping there are not too many.

Comment: Some thoughts to start with: x must be at most N^2. The number of products in the table is the number of factors of x, minus twice the number of factors < x/N. We can first go through the list of highly composite numbers and find the one with most products, say k products. We then look for numbers with at least k+1 factors; if x > N it must have at least k+3 factors; if x > 2N it must have k+5 factors (k+3 if x is odd), etc. Hopefully there aren't that many candidates, so a search might be quite quick. Or possibly not.

Comment: [This Erdos problem](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table) seems related.

Comment: @Michael The response given there concerns the work of Ford (2008), which is precisely what you will find mentioned elsewhere on MO at the link that ends my post here. (In the link you gave, Eric Naslund comments that the two MO posts are related; perhaps because he answered the other one!)

Comment: Based on a numerical experiment, it seems that these "most-often-occurring" numbers often *are* highly composite numbers. It's not true in all cases, though: For $n=1120$ we get $30240$, which is not a HCN; although this exception is apparently the sole one with $n\leq 4.10^4$. Furthermore, even this exceptional case happens to be *product of primorials* (just like all HCNs are) -- perhaps that could be a property shared by all the minimal-most-often-occurring numbers?

Comment: The number of representations grows like $$\exp\left({\frac{\log n \log 2}{\log \log n}(1+o(1))}\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

Here are some experimental data. I just used brute force to compute the (smallest) most occuring number $a_n$ and its multiplicity $b_n$ for $1\leq n\leq 1000$. E.g., 
$$a_{1000}=27720=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\ , \qquad b_{1000}=58\ .$$
The following figures show list plots of the $a_n$ and the $b_n$. Note that the $a_n$ are not monotone increasing.

[image]

[image]